# Why do OpenStruct values change when a hash with its dumped values change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openstruct

I'd like to know what's happening.

When I do the following:

```
new_struct = OpenStruct.new()
new_struct.color = 'Red'
new_struct.number = 4
```

This results in:

```
#<OpenStruct color="Red", number=4>
```

If I then create and change some params:

```
params = { first: new_struct.marshal_dump }

params[:first][:color] = 'Orange'
```

This results in the OpenStruct changing to:

```
#<OpenStruct color="Orange", number=4>
```

Why does this OpenStruct change if I change the params hash?  And is there a way to change the params hash without changing the OpenStruct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that suprising, `marshal_dump` returns the hash with the namespace of the OpenStruct object, which is mutable like any other hash. If you want to prevent this behavior, clone it:

```
params = {first: new_struct.marshal_dump.clone}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured there had to be some reason.  The OpenStruct was one of the columns in my db and it surprised me that it was changing.

Answer (score 1):

From the marshal_dump() entry for OpenStruct on ruby-doc:

> Provides marshalling support for use by the Marshal library.
>   Returning the underlying Hash table that contains the 
>   functions defined as the keys and the values assigned to them.

The hash you get from `marshal_dump()` is actually the underlying representation of the OpenStruct, so any changes in the hash will be reflected in the object.  You could always clone the hash to get around this.